# swift write to screen from delegate

Tags: swift, swift2

I've only been working with Swift for the last month please forgive me if I missed something everyone should know.  I have been tasked with creating an app that will receive an `APN` (Apple Push Notification) containing a the document number of a sales order that requires approval.  The app will display details about the sales order and present the user with an accept or reject option.  I built a proof of concept that works perfectly with the `APN`.  When I add the `APN` functionality I create an instance of the `ViewController` and use it to get the order details.  I stored the order details in a global variable that is available to both classes (delegate and `ViewController`).  Everything works great until I try to write order details to the screen.  It fails with:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

In `AppDelegate.swift` I set

```
 var vc = ViewController.self
```

In func

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

I process the `APN` and call

```
vc.init().LogonServiceLayer()
```

Everything works great until it tries to write to the screen.  I try to write to `CardNameLabel.text`.  I have `CardNameLabel` defined as

```
 @IBOutlet weak var CardNameLabel: UILabel!
```

I'm certain that I must create some sort of the an initialization function/constructor for my class.  I've tried something like:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    // Your intializations
    CardNameLabel.text = String ()
}

required init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    //Do whatever you want here
    CardNameLabel.text = String ()
}
```

This will compile but now it fails in the constructor instead of when I am trying to update the label on the screen.  Please forgive me if I'm missing something really obvious but so far I haven't found a way to update the labels on the screen using the instance of my class created in the delegate module.

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Duncan

Comment: In which line of code, you have a bug that is described in the question?

Comment: If I create an instance of ViewController.self in my delegate what actions do I have to take to write to the fields on the screen.  I have a label called CardNameLabel.  I want to update CardNameLabel.text.  In the viewController this works fine.  In the delegate I create var vc = viewController.self.  I later call vc.logon which calls a function to update CardNameLabel.text.  This call crashes the app because the vc object cannot touch the screen controls.  How can I use this instance of the viewController class to update the screen controls?